# Python 2.7 Subprocess shell result to label

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, output

I want to put the outcome of subprocess (shell) command into the label. The command works, but the label shows "0", however, in command prompt, the result is shown correctly, but I need it to be showed in label.

```
 def gauti():
        imti = tekstas.get("1.0", "end-1c")
        info = subprocess.call("id '{imti}' ".format(imti=imti), shell=True)
        w = Label(root, text= "info")
        w.pack(side = BOTTOM)
```

Comment: Did you read [the documentation for `subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)?  How about the other functions on that page?

Comment: Other functions don't really work out for me.  I tried Popen, but it gave me `<subprocess.Popen object at 0x7fa485357bd0>` in the label.